# Reorder Buffer commit

Tags: cpu-architecture

When having an Out-of-Order execution processor with a reorder buffer (ROB) and branch speculation, I understand that the changes are not being made until the ROB has performed a commit.

The results of the functional units (FUs) write their result on lets say a common data bus (CDB) and on the ROB when finished executing. The ROB can then decide if the branch was successfully predicted and if so commit otherwise the ROB is flushed.

What I don't understand is what happens to the reservation station updates that came from the CDB broadcasts of the FUs, should they not be flushed/rolled back somehow?

An example I can up with (maybe not the best)

```
addi $s1, $zero, 8
addi $s2, $zero, 9

addi $s3, $zero, 0
bneq $s1, $s2, L1
addi $s3, $s3, 1     // first increment
L1:
addi $s3, $s3, 2     // second increment
```

$s3 is initialized to 0, 
then a miss-prediction of the branch causes $s3 to increase by 1. The result is broadcasted to the RSs.

$s3 is now ready to start executing for the second increment of 2. At the same time the branch miss-prediction is detected and the ROB is flushed, however the RS of the adder is not changed, so $s3 now has a wrong value and was never in the ROB to be flushed.

How is this solved?

I suspect that I am missing something crucial, I am not very experienced, I just graduated and came up with this while revising.

[image]

Comment: As I understand it, on Intel CPUs at least, the ROB tracks all in-flight instructions inside the out-of-order part of the pipeline, including ones that are still in the RS waiting to execute.  So instructions are added to *both* the ROB and the RS when they issue into the out-of-order part of the core.  I think this design is nearly universal.  You're right that you need to be able to keep track of every instruction that's still speculative somehow.

Comment: There's a paper about "kilo-instruction processors" (i.e. out-of-order window >= 1k) where they propose checkpointing architectural state, and rolling back to last-known-good state on detecting mispredicts / exceptions that mean the current state is bogus.  But critically, they don't need a ROB that big because they don't need to remember how they got to the current state, just that they can go back to a checkpoint and retry to support precise exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

When the branch is predicted as taken, the update to `$s3` (the first increment) will not update the actual register `$s3`, that data will be buffered in the reorder buffer. When it is detected the misprediction, the reorder buffer will be flushed. Anyway the bottom line, to the best of my knowledge, is the original register will not be updated until the branch is resolved, hence reorder buffer is used.

Comment: The OP knows this, and is asking *how* that's accomplished, in detail.  I'm not sure my comment on the question is what the OP is looking for, so I didn't post it as an answer yet.

Comment: @PeterCordes, Sorry I didn't see your comment when I was adding the answer. Anyway I thought the OP slightly missed the idea of speculative execution as s/he refereed to $3 having the updated value before the branch prediction is resolved.

Comment: posted my comment and a follow-up thought as an answer.

Comment: thank you for the reply, yes, my point is that $s3 at the second increment will have the values broadcasted on the CDB during the first increment in its RS and the values will be valid. If the ROB is flushed before the second increment is finished (or even started), then $s3 will have get wrong value.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, on Intel CPUs at least, the ROB tracks all in-flight instructions inside the out-of-order part of the pipeline, including ones that are still in the RS waiting to execute. So instructions are added to both the ROB and the RS when they issue into the out-of-order part of the core.

I think this design is nearly universal. You're right that you need to be able to keep track of every instruction that's still speculative somehow.

---

Also, all instructions that *depend on* instructions discovered to have been mis-speculated need to be flushed.  It's certainly easier to flush the whole ROB as you describe, and get back to the last non-speculative state.

So even though the second add still needs to be executed, the mis-speculation means its input might be wrong.  So it needs to be flushed, to avoid exactly the problem you're talking about.

Comment: I see, thanks, I was thinking that maybe OOO execution could only be performed on Basic Blocks between commits which kind of defeats the purpose or that maybe everything ends up being flushed (RSs, FUs and ROB) and reset the PC to the correct address.

Comment: @alex10791: more advanced designs can even track which instructions need to be flushed, and can keep executing instructions that were unaffected by the discovery of a branch misprediction, while the misprediction is being resolved.  I forget when Intel introduced this, but within the last 10 years I think.  First gen P6 had to throw away all speculative uops (instructions) when any misprediction was detected.  (I'm not really a CPU designer, I just know how they work so I can optimize for them.  Some of this is over-simplified, I'm sure.)

Comment: @PeterCordes do you mean that this selective flush can actually avoid flushing instructions that are _after_ the wrongly predicted point in program order on Intel? I.e., if you had a jump over the next instruction, and you predict it not taken, but it is actually taken, you end up executing mostly the same instructions anyway - can the CPU note which later instructions don't depend on the result of the mispredict? Or do you mean the much simpler case of it being smart enough to flush everything after the mispredict, but leave mostly everything before intact (i.e., avoiding a machine clear)?

Comment: @BeeOnRope: I meant flushing everything after the mispredict, keeping everything before.  Since you have to reissue along the correct path, you'd have to somehow avoid issuing instructions that you kept... sounds ridiculously complex to implement, and probably only moderate benefit.  (IDK how common it is in compiler output to only jump over a couple instructions that didn't affect the inputs to most of the later instructions, e.g. to do a conditional store or register update of a max-seen variable or something which isn't read again until same place next iter.)

Comment: Yes of course - I didn't think it had been implemented, but it would be very remarkable if it had been! Short jumps are very common in compiler output. Indeed any type of short `if` often boils down to a small forward jump (although the existence and improvement of conditional moves can remove some of them - but here the compiler has to make a judgement call  on branch probabilities). They are common enough that hardware "if conversion" seems to be [a thing](http://www.google.ch/patents/US9367314) - and I believe some POWER arch implemented but Google is failing me.

Comment: Sorry I was replying to prior version of comment which I don't think had the "... which didn't affect the input to most of the later instructions". Yeah, that is probably less common. Actually I'm interested if there is *any* kind of speculation failure that does something finer grained than replaying all instructions following the misspeculation location?

Comment: @BeeOnRope: Yeah, that was a later edit, since inserting new uops into the middle of a dependency chain seems unlikely.  I had been thinking that, but hadn't said it explicitly.  I'm not aware of any speculation failures that are finer-grained than rewinding to the point of mis-speculation, but since they wouldn't cause full stalls they might not even make it into optimization manuals.  Better ask someone more familiar with that level of internals, like \@KrazyGlew.